# TYPO3 News Title in breadcrumb with MenuProcessor

Tags: typo3, typoscript, breadcrumbs, data-processing, tx-news

is it possible to show the current news title in breadcumb with the MenuProcessor?

I've tried some with DatabaseQueryProcessor but I don't get the data.

Have someone a working example or a tutorial for me?

At the moment I have only this:

```
temp.breadcrumb = FLUIDTEMPLATE
temp.breadcrumb {
    templateName = breadcrumb
    templateRootPaths {
        10 = fileadmin/resources/private/template/menu/
    }
    partialRootPaths {
        10 = fileadmin/resources/private/template/partials/
    }
    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
        10 {
            special = rootline
            special.range = 0|-1
            includeNotInMenu = 1
            as = menuBreadcrumb
        }
        dataProcessing {
            10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            10 {
                if.isTrue.field = records
                table = tx_news_domain_model_news
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now there is a solution for it: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/stable/singlehtml/Index.html#custom-menu-processor

Comment: i have the same issue - if you got a solution, then add your answer here please ;) possibly helps others @GoatMachine

Comment: The url above is the solution for this issue

Comment: I prefer this URL with a better explaination of that feature: https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/main/en-us/singlehtml/Index.html#breadcrumb